# simple way of extracting values from string

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
s = '''Report:

      Location: (569P,921L)

      Band 1:

        Value: 12'''
```

I have to get the the followings:

```
x, y = 569, 921
```

How is the best and easiest way of doing it?

I do not like `re` because of complicated and confusing characters of using it.

I have successfully extracted what I required as follows:

```
x, y = int(s.split()[2].split(',')[0][1:-1]), int(s.split()[2].split(',')[1][:-2])
```

But your ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use  regular expression

Comment: I find re very complicated, so.

Comment: *"complicated and confusing characters"* or not, a regex *is* probably the best way to do this, although you haven't said how you would define *"best"*. If you already have code that works, what's the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe My 'best' means more simpler and easy to understand. Even my code is not so elegant, so.

Comment: Easy to understand for whom? You've already said you find regex confusing; is there other syntax we should be avoiding? If you're worried about elegance I would suggest you stop trying to do it in one line, but otherwise it's not clear what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you just directly pick up the integers before P and L splitted by ,

Comment: *"the integers before P and L splitted [sic] by ,"* is *precisely* the sort of thing regular expressions are good for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple regex would work for this case.

```
>>> s = '''Report:

  Location: (569P,921L)

  Band 1:

    Value: 12'''
>>> x,y = re.findall(r'\b\d+(?=[A-Z])', s)
>>> print(x,y)
569 921
```

`\b` word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. `\d+` matches one or more digits , `(?=[A-Z])` which must be followed by an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

`Report:\s*Location:\s*\(([0-9]*)P,([0-9]*)L\)\s*Band 1:\s*Value: 12`

This regex should work for your case

Full code:

```
m = re.match(
    r"Report:\s*Location:\s*\(([0-9]*)P,([0-9]*)L\)\s*Band 1:\s*Value: 12",
    your_string)
m.group(0)      # First Number
m.group(1)      # Second Number`
```

Answer (score 0):

By string find method:
Target content which is in between `(` and `)`

```
import traceback

lines = input.split("\n")
result = []
for i in lines:
    start_index = i.find("(")
    if start_index!=-1:
        end_index = i.find(")", start_index)
        if end_index!=-1:
            taget_content = i[start_index+1: end_index]
            tmp = taget_content.split(",")
            try:
                x = int(tmp[0][:-1])
                y = int(tmp[1][:-1])
                result.append((x,y))
            except:
                print "Exception during eval:-", traceback.format_exc() 

print result
```

output:

```
$ python test.py 
[(569, 921), (600, 900)]
```

---

By regular expression

```
input = '''Report:

      Location: (569P,921L)

      Band 1:

        Value: 12
      Location: (600P,900L)

      Band 1:

        Value: 12
        '''

import re

target = re.findall("\((.*)\)", input)
print "target content:-", target
result = []
for i in target:
    tmp = i.split(",")
    try:
        result.append((int(tmp[0][:-1]), int(tmp[1][:-1])))
    except:
         print "Exception during eval:-", traceback.format_exc() 


print "Result:-", result
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
target content:- ['569P,921L', '600P,900L']
Result:- [(569, 921), (600, 900)]
```

Comment: There seems to be very little point in your style of error handling. The traceback already tells you on which line the problem occurred, so adding a comment seems superfluous. It just adds an import and three lines of code for nothing; error handling should be much more specific, see e.g. http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/